# Bar chart of counts of 1/0 data by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, group-by

I'm completely stumped and have no-one to ask.

I have a pandas dataframe similar to the following just much larger, what I would like to do is create a bar graph for each district that shows how many birds were present, i.e. how many '1's there are in the column. The '1's stand for 'was present', '0' for 'not present'.

groupby district gives me nonsense numbers.

I'm sure it is something completely obvious, but I'm drawing a blank.

| district | area | year | swallow | sparrow | kite | finch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | a_1 | 2010 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| aaa | a_1 | 2011 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| aaa | a_1 | 2015 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| aaa | a_2 | 2009 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| aaa | a_2 | 2011 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| bbb | b_1 | 2009 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| bbb | b_1 | 2012 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which exact graph you expect. Here are a few hints.

Per district/bird:

```
(df
 .drop(columns=['area', 'year'])
 .groupby('district').sum()
 .plot.bar()
)
```

[image]

Per district, all birds:

```
(df
 .drop(columns=['area', 'year'])
 .groupby('district').sum().sum(1)
 .plot.bar()
)
```

[image]

Comment: The first one was what I was looking for. I'll try to be more concise in the future. Thank you so much!